# Using a filename variable in a for loop

Tags: batch-file, variables, for-loop

I have a directory with a file in it (actually it has a lot of files, but I figured getting one to work was the first step before building the loop to hit each file), that needs to be edited and saved with a similar filename.  Instead of manually typing in the filename, I'd like to use a variable containing the filename.

```
Sample Input Data
FileX.txt
Text line 
Text line 
Text line

Desired Output Data
FileX2.txt
1 Text line
2 Text line
3 text line
```

I can manage this with one file at a time, I'm struggling to write one script to look through the contents of a folder and do this to each text file within the folder.

I'm on windows 7 and this is what I have so far:

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set N=0
REM THE BELOW LINE IS THE VARIABLE I'M TRYING TO SET AND THEN HAVE PASSED AS THE FOR LOOP PARAMETER
Set F="FILENAME"

REM IF I SKIP A VARIABLE AND HARDCODE THE FILENAME IN THE BELOW LINE, IT WORKS FOR THE ONE FILE
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (FILENAMEVARIABLE.txt) do (
Set /a N=!N!+1
echo !N! %%a, >> !F!.txt
)
```

The opening statement of the for loop, is where I can't get the variable to take.  In FILENAMEVARIABLE.txt I have tried %%F, %F, !F!, and %%~nxf none of which manage to call the correct file to start the loop.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't get what you want to achieve. Please provide some sample data (both input and output); [edit] the question to add it, don't comment...

Comment: Are you saying you are trying to put the `FOR` command modifiers inside the FILENAMEVARIABLE.txt file?

Comment: desired I/O added to original question

Comment: not exactly your format, but maybe it's ok for you: `for %%a in (*.txt) do findstr /n "^" %%a >%~na.new`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I think you were trying to do:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For %%A In (*.txt) Do (Set "N=0"
    (For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=*" %%B In ("%%A") Do (Set /A N +=1
            Echo !N! %%B))>"%%~nA2%%~xA")
```

You could also use `FindStr`:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Tokens=1-2* Delims=:" %%A In ('FindStr /N "^" *.txt 2^Nul'
) Do >>"%%~nA2%%~xA" Echo %%B %%C
```

*In both of the above examples I have assumed that the source directory and script directory are the same.*